# Any pointers on using AngularFire2 With GAPI to Access Google Analytics Reporting

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics-api, angularfire2

**Angular:** Angular2 RC4

**Firebase:** Firebase3 (latest)

**AngularFire:** AngularFire2 (latest)

I'm looking at trying to access the Google Analytics Reporting v4 API. Something like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js). But using Angular2 goodness.

Has anyone had any luck with doing this? I've googled, but it doesn't seem to be that popular of a topic. It doesn't help that Angular2 is still pretty new, so there's that. Does anyone have any idea? I'm sure it's a thing. I think?

I've got authentication working with AngularFire2 and Firebase, that's a first step. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE 2018

Someone added [DefinitelyTyped/types/gapi.client.analytics](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.client.analytics) for the Google Analytics Client API V3. Following this link there's a README with instructions on how to install it and use it.

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

Back in 2016 this was my way of implementing it:

### src/index.html

In the index.html file of your app you need to add this in the `<head>` section:

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

---

### typings/browser/ambient/gapi/

You need to add the following namespaces to your typings:

- [DefinitelyTyped/types/gapi](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi)
- [DefinitelyTyped/types/gapi.auth2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.auth2)
- [DefinitelyTyped/types/gapi.analytics](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.analytics)

### src/app/+login/login.component.ts

This is the file of my component, here you need to use the `ngAfterViewInit()` to use the gapi an get the auth.

As an example, this is my auth function where I also transform the API callback into a promise:

```js
private authorize() : Promise<any> {
    var authCallback;
    let authData = {
        client_id: 'your-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
        immediate: true
    };

    let p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      authCallback = response => response.error? reject(response) : resolve(response);
    });

    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, authCallback);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Did this work for you? this doesnt seem right when using typescript

Comment: @RossRawlins it did work for me back in 2016. This is just an authorize method inside my component, it was called on `ngAfterViewInit`. I'll update the answer as my PR was merged already.

This is my typings: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.analytics

There's other typing: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.client.analytics

It includes a README saying how to use it. I hope it's helpful.