# How to Access Global Google Analytics Function in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-analytics

I have the Google Analytics tracking code in the `index.html` file as well as a page view tracker in the `app.component.ts` file. It tookHere is the code I have that is working.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  lastRoute = location.href;

  constructor(ga:any){
    setInterval(() => {
      if (location.href != this.lastRoute) {
         this.lastRoute = location.href;
         ga('send', 'pageview', this.lastRoute);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

The problem I was first having is "ga is not a function." The suggested fix was putting `declare var ga:Function;` right above export class in `app.component.ts`. That did not work, but putting `go:any` in the constructor's input did. However, now I want to track whenever someone opens a modal. I cannot access the Google Analytic's function from any other components. I tried using `ga:any` again and I am getting error's such as "cannot resolve all parameters." I just need for the component to allow me to call the ga function just like `app.component.ts` does.

Comment: Using the constructor is the wrong way.. please post your index.html..

Comment: The index file simply has the Google Analytics tracking code script. I commented out the ga() in the main script so that there aren't duplicates when I send page views from elsewhere.

Comment: add the ga js script to the head. maybe it's a Timing Thing.. and use the `declare` way. other way would be to use a service.

Comment: I think that I answered a similar question, but related to Google Analytics API here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39771047/2308745
and related to Google Sing In here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39770500/2308745

I hope this give you some light.